# Updating Android SDK Tools on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build an Android app with Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015. But when I opened Main.axml, it showed an error

> The installed Android SDK is too old, Newer is required.

After that, I try to upgrade Android SDK Tools from AVD Manager, However I got the following error message:

> Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 24.4.1 URL not found:
>   C:\PROGRA~1\Android\ANDROI~1\temp\tools_r24.4.1-windows.zip (Access is
>   denied)

How do I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Try to run as administrator

Comment: Tim Castelijns, It's not working, any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this problem.The problem was Xamarin itself was not updated, as a consequence SDK Manager could not able to found windows.zip file. Here is the solution to update Xamarin..

Visual Studio 2015 → Tools → Options → Xamarin → Other

Select the Xamarin for Visual Studio Updates as "Stable". 
Then click on Check Now and download Xamarin.

Now update the Android SDK Tools..

Go on Tools → Android → Android SDK Manager.
From there update the Android SDK tools.

To finish. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: hello golden gate, android SDK and xamarin SDK are same?

Answer (score 0):

The zip file is opened by other application or C:\PROGRA~1\Android has no write permission for you. Close all other applications (or if in boubt simply reboot) and check permission on that directory and add to your user write permission. However, if you have other tools like Android Studio, is better to have a shared sdk for all. In VS you can change sdk location in Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android settings menu.

Comment: I don't think it's all about write permission as updating version is basic functionality.

Comment: True. Try to find if some process keeps it open blocking access to others. I use Sysinternals tools like Process Explorer

Comment: Or... try to close VS and delete all files in android-sdk\temp\ directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest granting the SDK manager in your Android SDK directory Admin privileges:

Navigate to:

C:\PROGRA~1\Android\ANDROI~1\

Right-click AVD Manager > Properties > Compatibility > Run this program as an administrator